# Number of Non Congruent Trapeziums

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Find number of Mutually Non Congruent Trapeziums that can be formed using Side Lengths $1,2,3,4,5,6$

I actually do not know definition of Non Congruent Quadrilaterals. But i assumed that as far as Trapezium is concerned, Two Trapeziums $T_1$ and $T_2$ are Congruent if and only if their Corresponding Base angles are equal. will this be helpful to solve the problem?

Comment: Are repetitions allowed?

Comment: no repetitions  not allowed

Comment: Two geometric figures are congruent if and only if there is a rigid motion taking one to the other.

Comment: You have only 20 potential cases to select two parallel segments. Does this help?